# How to solve the button not work but not error on snack.expo

Tags: react-native, expo

https://snack.expo.io/@6040311706/5685dc

Help me please, Thanks you 
When I click the button, It not work

Answer (score 0):

Your poblem is not with the Button, you are missing one step of the [expo - facebook documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/#api)

```
Facebook.initializeAsync(appId: string | undefined, appName: string | undefined)
```

Calling this method ensures that the SDK is initialized. You have to call this method before calling logInWithReadPermissionsAsync to ensure that Facebook support is initialized properly.

Hope it helps!